# "Snippets" plugin doesn't work on gedit

Tags: gedit, lubuntu, plugin

Note: I already know the answer, I'm only sharing my experience.

Some gedit plugins doesn't work on Lubuntu, the most notable is the Snippets one. I get the following error when I click on Tools->Manage Snippets:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/snippets/document.py", line 95, in do_deactivate
    self.disconnect_signals(self.view)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gobject/propertyhelper.py", line 214, in __get__
    value = instance.get_property(self.name)
TypeError: unknown type (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems gedit does havea very large number of missing required dependencies, that rise up when you try to use it on environments that are not Unity or GNOME.

To get rid of this particular problem, you have only to install:

`sudo apt-get install python3-gi-cairo`

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=720724

Answer (score 1):

It's worked for me after removed and installed it again

`sudo apt-get remove gedit`

`sudo apt-get install gedit`

Try this two command lines, maybe it'll work too for you :)